# What's the meaning of the mentioned mantras

Tags: vedas

Would like to know ,what's the meaning of the below mentioned :
Jyothismatim Dwaasaadayami
Jytothishkrutam Dwaasaadayami
Jyotirvidam Dwaasaadayami
BhaaswaTim Dwaasaadayami
Jwalanthim Dwaasaadayami
Malmalaabhavantim Dwaasaadayami
Deepyamaanam Dwaasaadayami
Rochamaanam  Dwaasaadayamyajasram Dwaasaadayami
Bruhajyotisham Dwaasaadayami

Comment: Where did you hear this mantra? Do you know any online source?

Comment: I was attending one Hindu function last week, one of the brahmins chanted these .... cudnt talk to him later ..he was v.old ,  didnt stay at that place n left  seems its coming from Rik or Yajus ..not sure....